# how to set the QTableView header name in Pyqt4

Tags: python, header, pyqt4, qtableview

I want to know how can i set the custom header names in QTableview

when i create a QTableview i get the column and row header names as 1,2,3,4.
I want to know how can i set my own column and header titles.

---

I got the [solution](http://pastebin.com/he125QmB) as required, Hope it could help some one who comes across the same situation

Answer (score 16):

If you're using a `QTableView` with your own model you need to implement the [`headerData()`](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qabstractitemmodel.html#headerData) method in the model to return data for the header. Here's a snippet to show just column headings - change the `header_labels` value to change the header text.

```
class TableModel(QAbstractTableModel):

    header_labels = ['Column 1', 'Column 2', 'Column 3', 'Column 4']

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QAbstractTableModel.__init__(self, parent)

    def headerData(self, section, orientation, role=Qt.DisplayRole):
        if role == Qt.DisplayRole and orientation == Qt.Horizontal:
            return self.header_labels[section]
        return QAbstractTableModel.headerData(self, section, orientation, role)
```

Comment: I am using a `QtGui.QStandardItemModel()` as model that i am linking to `QtGui.QTableView()`. i am able to set the header with `setHeaderData()`

Comment: @PBLNarasimhaRao, actually `headerData()` is a virtual function of `QAbstractItemModel`, and your `QStandardItemModel` is a subclass of `QAbstractItemModel`. Please check http://srinikom.github.io/pyside-docs/PySide/QtCore/QAbstractItemModel.html#PySide.QtCore.PySide.QtCore.QAbstractItemModel.headerData/QAbstractItemModel.html#PySide.QtCore.PySide.QtCore.QAbstractItemModel.headerData](here)

Answer (score 1):

The original poster produced the following code as a solution (orginally posted in a pastebin link that was deleted by a moderator):

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class myWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(myWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.centralwidget  = QtGui.QWidget(self)
        self.view           = QtGui.QTableView(self.centralwidget)
        self.view.setSortingEnabled(True)
        self.gridLayout = QtGui.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.view, 1, 0, 1, 3)

        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel(self)

        for rowName in range(3) * 5:
            self.model.invisibleRootItem().appendRow(
                [   QtGui.QStandardItem("row {0} col {1}".format(rowName, column))
                    for column in range(3)
                    ]
                )
        for column in range(3):
            self.model.setHeaderData(column, QtCore.Qt.Horizontal,
                                      'Column %d' % int(column+1))
            for row in range(3 * 5):
                self.model.setHeaderData(row, QtCore.Qt.Vertical,
                                            'Row %d' % int(row+1))

        self.proxy = QtGui.QSortFilterProxyModel(self)
        self.proxy.setSourceModel(self.model)

        self.view.setModel(self.proxy)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app  = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = myWindow()
    main.show()
    main.resize(400, 600)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```